# Find out which quick action button was clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction, lightning-quickaction

I have dozens of classic quick action buttons (JavaScript) on the standard page and converting all to lightning and having each lightning components for every single button is too much maintain all the different components, my question is that possible to find out which action button is clicked from the page?

Comment: I've linked several relevant Q&A to your question. Unfortunately, the answer you're hoping for doesn't exist. For now, you need different components.

Comment: thanks for confirming.